# Is it possible to add (part of) the legend of the OSM standard map to the layout in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, legend, basemap

For a location reference map I've created in the layout of QGIS (version 3.16.4-Hannover), I have used OSM Standard as the base map. The base map covers a wide range of objects and land types (see https://osmand.net/help-online/map-legend). However, when adding the base map, no legend is provided in QGIS. Is it possible to load the legend into QGIS, and then display it in a layout?

This is the map I am currently working on. In this example, I would like to add a legend for the different types of land cover (e.g. dark green = pine forest, light green = X forest, etc.).

[image: Example map]

Can this be done automatically, or does one need to manually create the legend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link https://osmand.net/help-online/map-legend provided is not the legend from official OpenStreetMap tiles, it's the OsmAnd styles and they differs.

To get all legends possible for OSM Standard style, as mentioned in https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Standard_tile_layer#Map_key look at https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Standard_tile_layer/Key and then choose between clicking on tabs "Symbols", "Lines", "Areas". I'm not aware of an existing complete legend. You will need to pick from these 3 tabs to make your own legend you want to display (if I'm wrong, would be glad to know I missed the info)

There is a generic legend at https://www.openstreetmap.org on the right part but it's more a summarized one (see screenshot below). It differs depending on the map zoom levels. I does not seem to fit what you want from your question description. FYI, legends are the same from levels 0 to 6 included, unique for levels 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, the same for both levels 13 and 14, and the same from levels 15 to 19. I've made [a small project to scrap this legend](https://gist.github.com/ThomasG77/0f103baa5001934bf981bb7855d60a5e) for all levels. It's also possible to get them for each supported language on OpenStreetMap.org website.

[image: Openstreetmap.org legend panel]